# Dictionary to list of strings pair

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have the following dictionary:

```
{'PoP': 4, 'apple': 1, 'anTs': 2, 'poeT': 1}
```

And I wish to have a list of values like this:

```
['PoP, 4', 'apple, 1', 'anTs, 2', 'poeT,1']
```

Which is like having a list of tuples but without the parentheses.
Is there anyway to do this ?

Comment: Hi, what have you tried so far to achieve this goal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## TL;DR

```py
elts = {'PoP': 4, 'apple': 1, 'anTs': 2, 'poeT': 1}

res = ["{}, {}".format(key,value) for key, value in elts.items()]
```

## Extended Discussion

You want to iterate over the items in the dictionary and at each iteration stitch the appropriate key and value together in the manner which you want.

We'll start with a **for** loop.

```py
elts = {'PoP': 4, 'apple': 1, 'anTs': 2, 'poeT': 1}

res = []
for key, value in elts.items():
    res.append("{}, {}".format(key, value))
```

Now that our **for** loop is in what I call the *iterate-then-append* form, we can beat it into a one-liner.

```
elts = {'PoP': 4, 'apple': 1, 'anTs': 2, 'poeT': 1}


res = ["{}, {}".format(key,value) for key, value in elts.items()]
```

Answer (score 1):

A simple `for` loop can get it done:

```py
dict={'PoP': 4, 'apple': 1, 'anTs': 2, 'poeT': 1}
lst=[]
for key,value in dict.items():
    lst.append(f"{key},{value}")
print(lst)
```

Comment: That should be `dict.items()`, not `enumerate(dict)`. You could also do this in a list comprehension.

Comment: @khelwood, very true, just updated example. I did it quickly and didn't get an error, so thought it worked. And a list comprehension would work, but might not be the easiest to understand.

Answer (score 1):

Using string formatting and a list comprehension:

```
[f'{k} {v}' for k, v in data.items()]
```

Results:

```
['PoP 4', 'apple 1', 'anTs 2', 'poeT 1']
```

Answer (score 0):

With a list comprehension:

```
dict={'PoP': 4, 'apple': 1, 'anTs': 2, 'poeT': 1}
lst = [ k + ', ' + str(dict[k]) for k in dict.keys()]
```